# Properties of topology in $\mathbb{R}$ of 'half-positive/half-negative' open intervals

Tags: general-topology

On $X = \mathbb{R}$ consider the topology:

$\tau = \{(-a, a) : 0 \leq a \leq \infty\}$

I have to answer several questions about this topology of which I don't understand how to answer the following two:

**Question 1:** Is $(X, \tau)$ metrizable?

Even though it is 1st-countable, I don't think it is metrizable, but I don't know how to proof it. If it were metrizable, it's opens would be generated by open 'balls'. But here for any two opens $U_1, U_2$ either $U_1 \subset U_2$ or $U_2 \subset U_1$, this doesn't seem to be a property of a metric topology. Also, every open contains the same element, $0$, which doesn't seem to go well with being a metric topology. So it feels like this it isn't metrizable, but I don't know why.

**Question 2:** Show that any continuous function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is constant.

I think this has to do something with the connectedness of X. Even stronger, every subset of $X$ is connected. My attempt at a proof:

Take $n \in f(X)$, then $f^{-1}(\{n\})$ is closed so it is in the form $(-\infty, a] \cup [a, \infty)$ for $0 \leq a \leq \infty$. Now I somehow have to show that a must be $0$, but I don't know how.

Any hints?

Comment: "Also, every open contains the same element, $0$, which doesn't seem to go well with being a metric topology"; Indeed, it's even worse, the topology isn't even Hausdorff.

Comment: Q1: Metric spaces are Hausdorff. Q2: Notice that $f^{-1}(a) \cap f^{-1}(b) \neq \emptyset$ if at least one is not empty itself.

Comment: Another approach: let $a = f(0)$. Then, $f^{-1}(a)$ is a closed set which contains $0$. The only one being $X$. So, $f^{-1}(a) = X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: How can not being Hausdorff be "even worse" then every open containing $0$??? :-P

Comment: @AndréCaldas Every open set containing $0$ is even worse than not "going well with being a metric topology". It doesn't even go well with being Hausdorff.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh... got it! Sorry... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Note that $0$ is an element of *every* nonempty open set.  (This will contradict a basic separation axiom that all metrizable spaces satisfy.)
2. If $x \in X$ is such that $f(0) \neq f(x)$, use the Hausdorffness of the real line and continuity of $f$ to find disjoint open neighbourhoods of $0$ and $x$ in $X$.  (Which kind of contradicts the above.)

Answer (score 3):

1. Assume $X$ is metrizeable. Consider the open $r$-ball around $1$ where $r=d(1,0)$. It should be an open set containing $1$, but not $0$.
2. Consider $f^{-1}(f(0))$.

Answer (score 1):

1) it is not metrizable because it is not Hausdorff, since you cannot separate 0 of any other point by open sets (any open set has zero as an element).

2) The real line with the canonical topology is Hausdorff. Therefore, if f is continuous, the subset of X in which f coincides with the constant function equals to f (0) is a closed set.
What are the closed subsets of X? Which of them contains zero?
Only X is closed and contains zero in this topology.

Comment: Actually, you just need to see that points are closed in Hausdorff spaces. But 0 is not closed in X. Therefore X is not Hausdorff. And, since R is Hausdorff, the inverse image of 0 by f should be a closed subset of X containing 0: which means, in this case, all the space X